# Website not rendering after ember js implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

**Background**

I am attempting to build a blog using `ember.js` and it's dependencies. Basically, I "nav bar" on the left side and the content is displayed on the right side. Something like:

[image: BLOG LAYOUT]

The left side does not move while the right side; also, the left side has links to various pages.

**The problem**

I am using `ember.js` to implement the links to the posts and have the posts render to the blog content side. Currently, my implementation is not rendering anything. Below is the code:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({});

var posts = [{
    id: '0',
    title: 'Title and title',
   author: {name: 'Author'},
   date: new Date('15-11-2014'),
   content: 'Work and work.'
 },{
   id: '1',
   title: "Rails is Omakase",
   author: { name: "d2h" },
   date: new Date('12-27-2012'),
   excerpt: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world. Places where in order to eat, you must first carefully look over the menu of options to order exactly what you want.",
   body: "I want this for my ORM, I want that for my template language, and let's finish it off with this routing library. Of course, you're going to have to know what you want, and you'll rarely have your horizon expanded if you always order the same thing, but there it is. It's a very popular way of consuming software.\n\nRails is not that. Rails is omakase."
}, {
   id: '2',
   title: "The Parley Letter",
   author: { name: "d2h" },
   date: new Date('12-24-2012'),
   excerpt: "My [appearance on the Ruby Rogues podcast](http://rubyrogues.com/056-rr-david-heinemeier-hansson/) recently came up for discussion again on the private Parley mailing list.",
   body: "A long list of topics were raised and I took a time to ramble at large about all of them at once. Apologies for not taking the time to be more succinct, but at least each topic has a header so you can skip stuff you don't care about.\n\n### Maintainability\n\nIt's simply not true to say that I don't care about maintainability. I still work on the oldest Rails app in the world."  
}];

/*
  This will load the lists for the template to take
*/
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return posts;
  }
});

App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('post', {path: '/posts/:post_id'});
});

App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return posts[params.post_id];
  }
});

/*Some small variables that*/
App.name = "Blog name";
App.tag = "TAG";
App.stub = "Stub";
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300italic,700italic,300,700);

body {
  padding:50px;
  font:14px/1.5 Lato, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color:#777;
  font-weight:300;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color:#222;
  margin:0 0 20px;
}

p, ul, ol, table, pre, dl {
  margin:0 0 20px;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  line-height:1.1;
}

h1 {
  font-size:28px;
}

h2 {
  color:#393939;
}

h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color:#494949;
}

a {
  color:#39c;
  font-weight:400;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a small {
  font-size:11px;
  color:#777;
  margin-top:-0.6em;
  display:block;
}

.wrapper {
  width:860px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

blockquote {
  border-left:1px solid #e5e5e5;
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0 0 20px;
  font-style:italic;
}

code, pre {
  font-family:Monaco, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Lucida Console, Terminal;
  color:#333;
  font-size:12px;
}

pre {
  padding:8px 15px;
  background: #f8f8f8;  
  border-radius:5px;
  border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

th, td {
  text-align:left;
  padding:5px 10px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

dt {
  color:#444;
  font-weight:700;
}

th {
  color:#444;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
}

header {
  width:270px;
  float:left;
  position:fixed;
}

header ul {
  list-style:none;
  height:40px;
  
  padding:0;
  
  background: #eee;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8 0%, #dddddd 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f8f8f8), color-stop(100%,#dddddd));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8 0%,#dddddd 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8 0%,#dddddd 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8 0%,#dddddd 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8 0%,#dddddd 100%);
  
  border-radius:5px;
  border:1px solid #d2d2d2;
  box-shadow:inset #fff 0 1px 0, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.03) 0 -1px 0;
  width:270px;
}

header li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

header ul a {
  line-height:1;
  font-size:11px;
  color:#999;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:6px;
  height:40px;
}

strong {
  color:#222;
  font-weight:700;
}

header ul li + li {
  width:88px;
  border-left:1px solid #fff;
}

header ul li + li + li {
  border-right:none;
  width:89px;
}

header ul a strong {
  font-size:14px;
  display:block;
  color:#222;
}

section {
  width:500px;
  float:right;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}

small {
  font-size:11px;
}

hr {
  border:0;
  background:#e5e5e5;
  height:1px;
  margin:0 0 20px;
}

footer {
  width:270px;
  float:left;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:50px;
}

@media print, screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  
  div.wrapper {
    width:auto;
    margin:0;
  }
  
  header, section, footer {
    float:none;
    position:static;
    width:auto;
  }
  
  header {
    padding-right:320px;
  }
  
  section {
    border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-width:1px 0;
    padding:20px 0;
    margin:0 0 20px;
  }
  
  header a small {
    display:inline;
  }
  
  header ul {
    position:absolute;
    right:50px;
    top:52px;
  }
}

@media print, screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  body {
    word-wrap:break-word;
  }
  
  header {
    padding:0;
  }
  
  header ul, header p.view {
    position:static;
  }
  
  pre, code {
    word-wrap:normal;
  }
}

@media print, screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    padding:15px;
  }
  
  header ul {
    display:none;
  }
}

@media print {
  body {
    padding:0.4in;
    font-size:12pt;
    color:#444;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
    <title>Blog Title</title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div class="wrapper">
 
   <script type="text/x-handlebars">
   <!-- Header which is on the right side. -->
   <header>
  <h1> {{App.name}} </h1>
  <h2>{{App.tag}}</h2>
  <p> {{App.stub}}</p>

  <!-- Links to the main content -->
   
  <h3> Recent Content </h3> 
   <!-- Ember code to filter through five most recent posts --> 
   {{#each post in model}}
     <li> {{#linkTo "post" this}} {{post.title}} {{/linkTo}}</li>
   {{/each}}

   </header>

   <!-- Footer -->
      <footer>
        <p><small>Hosted on GitHub Pages &mdash; Theme by <a href="https://github.com/orderedlist">orderedlist</a> with heavy modifications from Jeel Shah</small></p>
      </footer>

      </script>
   <!-- Main content for the day. The rest of the content will be on the left 
     Ember code will surround this (?)
   -->
    
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <section>
   <h3> Welcome to my blog </h3>
    <p>
     {{outlet}}
    </p>
    </section>
   </script>
    </div>
 
 <!-- javascripts -->
    
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.9.0-beta.1/ember.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My Attempt**

I tried to make two different handlebar scripts, one which is a reference to posts i.e.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
          <section>
            <h3> Welcome to my blog </h3>
                <p>
                    {{outlet}}
                </p>
          </section>
         </script>
```

but that didn't work. I also tried to make a single handlebars scripts surrounding the entire `div` but that also didn't work.

If someone could point in the right direction as to what the problem is: I would forever be on in your debt. Thanks! `:)`

**Update**
I have updated the code for the `HTML/js`. It can be viewed [here](http://jsbin.com/vipajatuto/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre missing a few ideas of ember -
Naming is important. You have posts - which should be in a model and then use the fixture adapter to declare them.
You have a posts template but no posts route defined or in your router.

```
this.resource("posts", {path: "/posts"}, function(){
    this.resource("post", {path: "/:post_id"});
});
```

You have no index route in your router.

```
this.resource("index", {path: "/"}, function() {});
```

And you have no controllers at all by the looks of things.(though it looks like right now you dont need them)

If you are using ember I would suggest using ember-cli. It will help set up an app structure for you and help with naming conventions. http://www.ember-cli.com/

It would also be no harm in working through an ember tutorial - whether the one on the ember site itself or on a different site. Try to do one thats as recent as possible as the code is moving so fast that tutorials can become outdated quite quickly.

**LINKS**

```
{{#each post in model}}
    <li> {{#link-to "post" post}} {{post.title}} {{/link-to}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

so for links - {{#link-to "template" model}} where template is the template and model is the item youre passing with the link. So in your case its the "post" template and since you defined your model as post in your each statement you use that. via the docs http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/#toc_the-code-link-to-code-helper

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated the code, now only the links don't link. :/

Comment: links are written `{{#link-to}}`  - see answer above for amended code.